# Run two function at sametime in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a power shell script with two function.

```
function func1 {
}
function func2 {
}
func1
func2
```

I put the script in startup folder to start with windows startup.
The problem its only func1 works and I need that the two functions work as a loop, because both function watch if a file is copy to a folder.

If I have two script file, one for func1 and another for func2 its work, but I want to have both function in one script file.
what is missing?

Comment: Please show the actual code :) Seeing _how_ your functions are watching a file will make it easier to suggest ways of running it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what those functions do and return (or do not return anything or might not even finalize in case "*if a file is copy to a folder*" never happens)...

Anyways, you might invoke them parallel using the [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) and [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) till [`-any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job#-any) of the jobs is finished:

```
func1 {
    Sleep 5
    'File 1 is copied'
}
func2 {
    Sleep 3
    'File 2 is copied'
}

$function:func1, $function:func2 |Foreach-Object { Start-Job $_ } |Wait-Job -Any |Receive-Job

File 2 is copied
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. Another question, its possible clean a specific file in a folder only when windows start, after that do nothing. Its to add to previous code.